# russian name not showing on content header from section in php

Tags: php, email, character-encoding

i have try to send mail with russian name but its not working on outlook but showing correctly on gmail.. how can i fix it.. it show like this

```
  ÐÐ¾ÑÑÐ°Ð»Ðµ [info@stackoverflow.com]
```

i have try following code $subject = mb_encode_mimeheader('Потцале',"UTF-8");
but after this gmail also show same problem.. russian character display well on the body section but not on header of mail.

here is my code..

```
         <?php

         // if the url field is empty

         $emails='info@stackoverflow.com'; 
         $email='xyz@gmail.com';
         $con='Потцале Потцале Потцале Потцале';
         $subject = mb_encode_mimeheader('Потцале',"UTF-8");
         $msg='<html><head><meta              http-equiv="Content-Type"                                        content="text/html;             
         charset=utf-8" /></head><body>Потцале Потцале Потцале Потцале              </body></html>';
          $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
         $headers .='Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From:'.$subject.'<'.$emails.'> ' . "\r\n"; 

// then send the form to your email
            $ash = @mail( $email,$con,$msg,$headers);
            // @mail( $email,'Submit Form','Thanks For Contacting Us We              Will Contact You Shortly',$headers);

             if($ash)
         {
         echo 'send';
         }
         else
         {
         echo ' Not Send send';
         }

?>

  <html>
```

Thanks!

## Thanks

We'll get back to you as soon as possible.

after subject.. please help me ..

Comment: Are you using utf-8 character encoding everywhere?

Comment: then what i will use for it if i don't use utf character the mail body also show different charcter...